# Add an Event Emitter dynamically in a service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am working with a project and using angular 4. I have a situation where in i have to add an event eventemitter to the object dynamically in a service. ie
i have an object which i receive from a service by doing

```
this._service.butons.subscribe((buttons) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(buttons));

        })
```

which looks like following

```
{  
   "save":{  
      "label":"Submit",
      "action":"save",
      "disabled":true
   },
   "discard":{  
      "label":"Discard"
   }
}
```

I have to add an eventemitter to save and discard button objects dynamically that will emit an event when the 'disabled' value changes. Is there any way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html

Comment: @crooksey is it the answer for the asked question ? i dont see adding an emitter part

Comment: How do you make changes to the `disabled` property?

Comment: You need to add a new property to save and discard objects? For ex : discard object will be like "discard": { "label": "Discard", "new_prop":"newValue" }. Is that what you want?

Comment: i need to add an event emitter when he discard's property, ie disabled changes from true to false or vice versa..